# Login with Facebook sending data to MySQL/PHP Database

Tags: php, android, laravel, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm implementing the Facebook and Google login in Android Studio.  The data gets saved to the database but in response in the API I get a **false** result. I'm new to programming but I have done research but still cannot get through it. I have implemented as follows...

My PHP function is:

```
public function facebookViaAPI(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'device_type' => 'required|in:android,ios',
            'device_token' => 'required',
            'accessToken' => 'required',
            //'mobile' => 'required',
            'device_id' => 'required',
            'login_by' => 'required|in:manual,facebook,google'
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => $validator->messages()->all()]);
    }

    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless();
    $FacebookDrive = $user->userFromToken($request->accessToken);

    try {

        $FacebookSql = User::where('social_unique_id', $FacebookDrive->id);
        if ($FacebookDrive->email != "") {
            $FacebookSql->orWhere('email', $FacebookDrive->email);
        }
        $AuthUser = $FacebookSql->first();
        if ($AuthUser) {
            $AuthUser->social_unique_id = $FacebookDrive->id;
            $AuthUser->device_type = $request->device_type;
            $AuthUser->device_token = $request->device_token;
            $AuthUser->device_id = $request->device_id;
            $AuthUser->mobile = $request->mobile ?: '';
            $AuthUser->login_by = "facebook";
            $AuthUser->save();
        } else {
            $AuthUser = new User();
            $AuthUser->email = $FacebookDrive->email;
            $name = explode(' ', $FacebookDrive->name, 2);
            $AuthUser->first_name = $name[0];
            $AuthUser->last_name = isset($name[1]) ? $name[1] : '';
            $AuthUser->password = bcrypt($FacebookDrive->id);
            $AuthUser->social_unique_id = $FacebookDrive->id;
            $AuthUser->device_type = $request->device_type;
            $AuthUser->device_token = $request->device_token;
            $AuthUser->device_id = $request->device_id;
            $AuthUser->mobile = $request->mobile ?: '';
            $AuthUser->picture = $FacebookDrive->avatar;
            $AuthUser->login_by = "facebook";
            $AuthUser->save();
        }
        if ($AuthUser) {
            $userToken = $AuthUser->token() ?: $AuthUser->createToken('socialLogin');
            return response()->json([
                "status" => true,
                "token_type" => "Bearer",
                "access_token" => $userToken->accessToken
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => "Invalid credentials!"]);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage() . "\n" . $e->getTraceAsString()]);
    }
}
```

My code for android is:

```
 public void login(final String accesstoken, final String URL, final String Loginby) {
    Log.d("Login Enter","::::::");
    customDialog = new CustomDialog(context);
    customDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (customDialog != null)
        customDialog.show();
    final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("device_type", "android");
    json.addProperty("device_token", device_token);
    json.addProperty("accessToken", accesstoken);
    json.addProperty("device_id", device_UDID);
    json.addProperty("login_by", Loginby);
    json.addProperty("mobile",mobileNumber);
    Log.e(TAG, "login: Facebook" + json);
    Ion.with(ActivitySocialLogin.this)
            .load(URL)
            .addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
           .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer"+SharedHelper.getKey(context, "token_type")+" "+SharedHelper.getKey(context, "access_token"))
            .setJsonObjectBody(json)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    // do stuff with the result or error
                   // Log.d("Completed Enter" , "::::::::"+result.toString());
                    Log.d("Exception" , "::::::::"+e);

                    Log.d("Completed Enter result" , "::::::::"+result);

                    if ((customDialog != null) && customDialog.isShowing())
                        customDialog.dismiss();
                    if (e != null) {
                        if (e instanceof NetworkErrorException) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.oops_connect_your_internet));
                        } else if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
                            login(accesstoken, URL, Loginby);
                        } else{
                            Log.d("Access Fail" , "::::::::");
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    if (result != null) {
                        Log.v(Loginby + "_Response", result.toString());
                        Log.d("Response" + "_Response", result.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                            String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
                            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                                SharedHelper.putKey(ActivitySocialLogin.this, "token_type", jsonObject.optString("token_type"));
                                SharedHelper.putKey(ActivitySocialLogin.this, "access_token", jsonObject.optString("access_token"));
                                if (Loginby.equalsIgnoreCase("facebook"))
                                    SharedHelper.putKey(ActivitySocialLogin.this, "login_by", "facebook");
                                if (Loginby.equalsIgnoreCase("google"))
                                    SharedHelper.putKey(ActivitySocialLogin.this, "login_by", "google");

                                if (!jsonObject.optString("currency").equalsIgnoreCase("") && jsonObject.optString("currency") != null)
                                    SharedHelper.putKey(context, "currency", jsonObject.optString("currency"));
                                else
                                    SharedHelper.putKey(context, "currency", "$");
                                //phoneLogin();
                                getProfile();
                            } else {
                                GoToBeginActivity();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else {
                        Log.d(" Login Failure" , "::::::::");
                        displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

My Log print response of Exception **e** and **result** are respectively as follows:

```
Exception: ::::::::null

Response_Response: {"status":false,"message":"Trying to get property of non-object\n#0 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php(66): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/aayocab/p...', 66, Array)\n#1 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php(71): Laravel\\Passport\\ClientRepository->personalAccessClient()\n#2 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/passport/src/HasApiTokens.php(67): Laravel\\Passport\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory->make(74, 'socialLogin', Array)\n#3 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/SocialLoginController.php(171): App\\User->createToken('socialLogin')\n#4 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\SocialLoginController->facebookViaAPI(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#5 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('facebookViaAPI', Array)\n#7 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(189): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\SocialLoginController), 'facebookViaAPI')\n#8 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(144): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()\n#9 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(653): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#10 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#11 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#12 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#13 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#14 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#15 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), '60', '1')\n#16 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#17 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#18 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(655): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))\n#19 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(629): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#20 /home/aayocab/public_html/aayocab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(607): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#21 /h
```

Comment: What's the message for the Exception $e?

Comment: Replace the line `return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => trans('api.something_went_wrong')]);` with `return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage() . "\n" . $e->getTraceAsString()]);`, this will allow you to know the exception message and trace.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exception response @MarcoFlorian

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/406#issuecomment-321143172

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/406#issuecomment-335854963